# Can I get the size of the bytes that are in a Indy TCP connection buffer but are not yet transmited?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to send some (big) files over an internet connection at the maximum possible speed, using Indy TCP. I have writen a simple app to test how Indy TCP Client-Server connection works.

What I discovered is that:

- all writes to the socket happens instantly
- even if `Disconnect` after I write, the data is still received on the other side, if it is read
- the data can have any size; I wrote 100 MB and I received every bit.

So it means that there is a transmission buffer on the socket that is writen to. And it looks like it can have any size... If I write a large amount of data (let's say 100 MB), I think it is not transmited in a single operation, but in small chuncks (let's say 1 MB). So, as the data is transmitted, that buffer shrinks until it reaches zero, when all data is transmitted. What I need is the length of that buffer at any time, to know when it needs to be filled, so I cand write continuously without thaking up the whole computer memory.

I don't know if what I wrote here makes sense... If not, please tell me to delete the question and ask a more general question. What I want in the end, is to send a file through a Indy TCP connection at the highest speed possible (meaning asynchronous), but with a progress bar and a cancel button.

This is the test app:

```
procedure TClient.Execute;
var Cmd: Cardinal;
    Txt: String;
    Buff: TIdBytes;
    Size: Integer;
begin
 Size:= 5000000;
 SetLength(Buff, Size);
 Buff[0]:= 33;
 Buff[Size-1]:= 55;

 Client.Connect;
 Cmd:= 1234;
 Client.Socket.Write(Cmd);
 Client.Socket.Write(Size);
 Client.Socket.Write(Buff);
 Txt:= 'client finished transmision';
 SendMessage(RWnd, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Txt), 0);
 Client.Disconnect;
 Txt:= 'client disconected';
 SendMessage(RWnd, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Txt), 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var Cmd: Cardinal;
    Mess: String;
    Buff: TIdBytes;
    Size: Integer;
begin
  Mess:= 'Server ready';
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Mess), 0);

  Cmd:= AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadUInt32;
  Mess:= 'Server receive command';
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Mess), 0);

  if Cmd = 1234 then begin
   Size:= AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadInt32;
   Sleep(4000);
   Mess:= 'Server start reading';
   SendMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Mess), 0);
   AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadBytes(Buff, Size);
   Mess:= IntToStr(Buff[0]) + ' / ' + IntToStr(Buff[Size-1]);
   SendMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Mess), 0);
  end;

  Mess:= 'Server closed connection';
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Mess), 0);
end;
```

Comment: it depends on your protocol over tcp. send the full file size at the very beginning of the transmission or as a header property

Comment: I don't think it depends on my protocol... It's more like a Indy internal mechanism... if it's not something low-level... I can write the whole file at once to the connection socket, but I dont have that much RAM (for this internal buffer). And I want to set a maximum amount for this buffer, and when the data is read on the other size and it empties, write more data to it, so that the transfer be continuous...

Comment: but you can do that i wrote as well

Comment: But I don't understand how that helps me...

Comment: If you dont have enough memory, you could use two small memory buffer (like 10/100MB) and then read with buffer 1 then write that buffer to file (async) and read using buffer 2. And when buffer 2 is full write that to file async and use buffer1 again to read data again. Etc. But be sure to check the async write of the buffer is done, before writing the other buffer...

Comment: you want to know the total size of the file to handle progress bar state, do you? i dont understand what you not understand.

Comment: No, I don't want that. I want to know how many bytes are in the write buffer, as they are transmited...

Comment: The write buffer is in the socket's internals in the OS kernel. You don't have access to know how much data is in the write buffer at any given moment. You can only know how much data you ask to put in the buffer, and you can ask the OS to pre-size the buffer (but there is no guarantee it will honor that request). You don't need to know the actual buffer content in order to display a progress bar. Simply display the percentage of data you ask to send.

Comment: Thanks, @RemyLebeau ... I was afraid of that :( Of course, it's simple to display the percentage of data sent on a progress bar, but what interests me most is to have a continous flow of data beteween both sides... That's why I needed to know the write buffer size, to feed it before it empties but not to exceed a certain maximum limit, writing to it.

Comment: @MarusNebunu you don't need to handle that manually. Just send as much data as you can, as fast as you can. TCP will do the necessary throttling for you. If the write buffer fills up, it will block you from sending more data until space clears up. If the buffer clears before you send more data, then you are not sending fast enough in your own code.